# Highlighting the middle letter in the supplied text

Tags: tkinter

I need to be able to highlight a letter in a different color in the text supplied to entry_sb than in self.canvas.text. As a result, the text should run, and the letter that will be emphasized in the word should be highlighted.

```
class Application(object):

     def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg='black')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas_text = self.canvas.create_text(180, 130, text='',anchor=tk.NW,fill="white",font=('Arial',18))


        self.entry = tk.Entry(root)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.entry_cb)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.focus()
        root.mainloop()
     def animate_text(self, text, delta):
        delay = 0
        for i in range(len(text)+1):
            update_text = lambda s=text[i - 1:-1]: self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.canvas_text, text=s)
            self.canvas.after(delay, update_text)
            delay += delta


     def entry_cb(self, event):
       # s = self.entry.get().split()
        s = 'London is the capital of Great Britain'.split()
        s += [s[-1]]
        self.animate_text(s, skorost)

skorost = 400

app = Application()
```

Comment: This would be much easier with a `Text` widget. Is there a reason you require a canvas?

Comment: As Bryan Oakley pointed out, its better if you use `Text` widget instead, it has tags feature. While `Entry`s don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `tkinter.Text` widget instead.

### Procedure

- Configure a tag named highlight, which is to be added for the text.
- Create a highlight function which searches and highlights the words left
- Call the highlight function everytime text on canvas is edited

### Fix

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg='black')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas_text = self.canvas.create_text(180, 130, text='',anchor=tk.NW,fill="white",font=('Arial',18))

        self.entry = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=1)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.entry_cb)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.focus()

        self.entry.tag_config('highlight', background='yellow')

        root.mainloop()

    def highlight(self, text):
        # clean all tags
        self.entry.tag_remove('highlight', '1.0', tk.END)

        count = tk.IntVar()
        index = self.entry.search(text, '1.0', tk.END, count=count)
        if index == "": 
            return
        self.entry.mark_set("matchStart", index)
        self.entry.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
        self.entry.tag_add("highlight", "matchStart", "matchEnd")
    
    def animate_text(self, text, delta):
        delay = 0
        for i in range(len(text)+1):
            def foo(s):
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.canvas_text, text=s)
                self.highlight(s)
            
            update_text = lambda s=text[i - 1:-1]: foo(s)
            self.canvas.after(delay, update_text)

            delay += delta

    def entry_cb(self, event):
        s = self.entry.get('1.0', tk.END).split()
        s += [s[-1]]
        self.animate_text(s, skorost)
        return 'break'

skorost = 400

app = Application()
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, text widget indexes should be strings, not floats. Floats work sometimes, but it's a bad habit to use them.

Comment: true, fixed it!

Comment: the text is highlighted in the bottom line, but I thought to do it in the output of the window itself (text that is on a black background)

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you trying to highlight text left in the entry? why would you highlight text in the canvas since its the thing being animated? what do you mean by "the letter that will be emphasized in the word should be highlighted"?

Comment: To put it simply, I need to highlight the word of the text, which is projected in an animated form